# Why does PHP chunk_split() default to a chunk length of 76?

Tags: php, chunking

Can someone explain why 76 characters is the default, and why that might be useful in practice?

Comment: first paragraph in php doc: rfc 2045...

Comment: Checking the comment in the manual can help sometimes: http://php.net/manual/en/function.chunk-split.php#114423

Comment: Yes, I did see that RFC 2045 note but I want to know why this number was actually chosen.

Comment: another 'info' byte [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.base64-encode.php#111942) puts chunk_split in context of b64 encoding. Gives you a bit of perspective on the `why`.

Comment: @YvesLeBorg That's very helpful--so 76 is the longest number of characters possible, not counting the CRLF at the end, that lets "each line get decoded independently of the others, and the decoded chunks can then be concatenated together or written out sequentially" as per [the base64-encode documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.base64-encode.php#111942)

Comment: @YvesLeBorg do you know if there are any other use cases or is is 76 specifically to work well with base64 encoding?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because RFC 2045 semantics specify that encoded lines must not be longer than 76 characters, not counting the trailing CRLF.

**Addendum:**
[Warning: Highly Pedantic Presentation Follows]

There are several different mechanisms for "Content-Transfer-Encoding" and two of the main methods (for this discussion) are "quoted-printable" and "Base64".

*Quoted-Printable* encoding is intended to represent data that correspond to printable characters in the US-ASCII character set. Base64 Content-Transfer-Encoding is designed to represent arbitrary sequences of data in a form that need not be humanly readable. Both encodings transform their input from an arbitrary domain into material safe to carry over *restricted transports*.

"Restricted transports" means a transport that can only handle 7-bit data, i.e. acoustic modems and analog lines. In other words, it's designed to be reliable in really crappy conditions.

Because *Quoted-Printable* is generally expected to be line-oriented and because RFC 2045 dates back to 1996 it seems reasonable to assume the spec writers expected the text would be seen on an 80 column CRT or printed by a dot-matrix printer or TTY. If that is true, then the 76 character default would be a desire to accommodate the lowest common denominator of the available display technology.

If you're wondering why mess with *Base64* in the case of text-only transport it is because there are several kinds of substrings cannot be generated according to   the *quoted-printable* encoding rules. *Base64* doesn't have these same restrictions which makes its use sensible.

Comment: Technically this is the correct answer so I'll mark it as such. I was really looking for an explanation as to WHY this was the number chosen, for PHP and for RFC 2045. For anyone wondering: read [this](http://php.net/manual/en/function.base64-encode.php#111942), which explains how 76 characters is the most that plays nice with base64 encoding.

Comment: @Anton, I dug deeper into RFC 2045 and have a theory as to why 76 characters was chosen. See the addendum to my answer.